# Windows installer patching a running executable

Tags: windows, windows-installer, executable, patch, msp

I created a patch (MSP package) that mainly updates the executable of the application. As a test I tried running the patch when the executable is running. Strangely, enough the executable was replaced. I.e. windows normally doesn't allow to modify the EXE file that has an open handle to it.
 How does Windows Installer handle it? I know about the trick with renaming the executable and placing another one instead but how does msiexec handle this and is it described anywhere (I looked through the docs but can't find it)? I'd appreciate any replies as I'm mainly interested how reliable this behavior is.

Thanks!

Comment: What application if I may ask are you referring to here?

Comment: Most likely the restart manager handles this for you:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373524(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover: it's an executable I built that is installed and patched using Windows Installer

Comment: @BogdanMitrache: the point is my executable is not restarted, it runs normally but its contents and size change after the patch is applied (but no restart of the system or my executable ever happens at all).